# Load nested trait class

Tags: scala, reflection, traits

I have a piece of code under "test" package as below

```
object TestTraitsUnderObject {

  trait InnerOperation[T] {

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Class.forName("test.OuterOperation")
    Class.forName("test.TestTraitsUnderObject.InnerOperation")

  }
}

trait OuterOperation[T] {

}
```

seems I can load the class for Outer trait correctly , but for nested trait, the classpath is incorrect ? why is that ? How I can load the `nested trait class correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$`

`Class.forName("test.TestTraitsUnderObject$InnerOperation")`

Comment: Thanks, Another question ,how to load class for nested class in a package object ?

Comment: `"test.package$Inner"` if you have `Inner` in test package object